# How to understand the "$0" "$@" after `exec python3 "$0" "$@" `

Tags: python, bash, sh, zsh, exec

I do not quite follow the following code snippet from https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/configure#L6-L16.

In particular, what does `"$0" "$@"` mean right after ```` sh -c ```<command>``` ```` ?

For now, I understand that by running `./<this_file_name>`, the program would check the existing available python and execute the same file (as `exec`  will exit the current program after it successfully finished ) once we find the existing version.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Locate an acceptable Python interpreter and then re-execute the script.
# Note that the mix of single and double quotes is intentional,
# as is the fact that the ] goes on a new line.
_=[ 'exec' '/bin/sh' '-c' '''
command -v python3.11 >/dev/null && exec python3.11 "$0" "$@"
command -v python3.10 >/dev/null && exec python3.10 "$0" "$@"
exec python "$0" "$@"
''' "$0" "$@"
]
del _
import sys
...
```

Comment: `$0` is the name of the shell script, `$@` is all the arguments to the shell script. This is basic shell scripting.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the reply. I try to understand what does it mean when it is put after `sh -c ```<command>``` `

Comment: It's basically just passing the arguments of the original script to python.

Comment: @Barmar but why do we have an another `"$0" "$@"` right after `exec python*` ? e.g. before the second `'''`

Comment: That's how you pass arguments to the python script. It's taking the shell arguments and turning them into python arguments.

Comment: What I don't understand is why it's doing `del _` immediately after assigning the variable. Did you leave out a call to `subprocess.run()`?

Comment: @Barmar `del _` makes sense once we understand that above snippet is both a VALID python script and a VALID shell script (until the `]`)

Comment: @Philippe That's the part that I was having trouble figuring out.

Comment: That is a tricky piece of polyglot code. It's sh that execs sh that execs python. The sh interpreter will not error on the python code since it never gets that far before getting exec-ed away.

Comment: In most of the cases, you'll achieve the same by just adding `#! /usr/bin/env python3`, you don't have to add any new python version to the code and you let the user decides which one is first in PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man sh`

> ```
> -c  Read commands from the command_string operand instead of
>     from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set
>     from the command_name operand and the positional parameters
>     ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands.
> ```

an example :

```
/bin/sh -c '
   echo \$0 is $0
   echo "All the arguments are : $@"
' dollar-0 arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Output is :

```
$0 is dollar-0
All the arguments are : arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I now understand what the code mean.